# How to programmatically set AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender.DefaultView to "Years" view dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When trying to set the DefaultView for CalendarExtender to "Years" view ; it gives compile time error for below code

`AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender calenderDateFrom = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
     calenderDateFrom.ID = "calFrom";
     calenderDateFrom.DefaultView = "Years";`

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarDefaultView'

Answer (score 0):

Found the trick; it is as below :

calenderDateFrom.DefaultView = AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarDefaultView.Years;